# How to bind AccordionItem Visibility when using Accordion.ItemTemplate in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding, accordion, visibility

Accordion item Visibility property can be bound like this:

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion x:Name="MyAccordion">
    <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
        ...
    </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
</layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

But how to bind it when using Accordion.ItemTemplate?

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion ItemsSource="{Binding AcordionItems}" x:Name="MyAccordion">
    <layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
    <layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </layoutToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
</layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

I can bind IsVisible to elements inside DataTemplate, but then an empty accordion item is displayed. I need to be able to show/hide the whole accordion item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using StackPanel with multiple Accordions:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AcordionItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <layoutToolkit:Accordion Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter=
                    {StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                    <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
                        ...
                    </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
                </layoutToolkit:Accordion>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```